# Pom.xml giving depending errors when Accessing datastore from standalone java application

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am getting error. I am not able to resolve this issue even after changing guava versions. I am using gcloud java to connect from local java app to the cloud datastore and i am getting this dependency error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getFirst(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

<dependencies>
    <dependency>                        <!-- REQUIRED -->
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  <!-- Java Servlet API -->
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>           <!-- Provided by the Jetty Servlet engine -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- Java Server Pages -->
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- JSP standard tag library -->
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- Apache Taglibs -->
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- Google Cloud Client Library for Java -->
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>gcloud-java</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- Google API client - for stuff that's not in gcloud-->
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- Google+ API Client Library for Java -->
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev339-1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind -->
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- Google Core Libraries for Java -->
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>  <!-- https://github.com/google/guava/wiki -->
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ -->
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/ -->
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                        <!-- Apache Database Connection Pool API -->
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>My pom.xml has the following dependencies:
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check Your container modules version.

For example, GlassFish Server have old version of guava lib.
If possible (and actual) check Your "GlassFish_Server/glassfish/modules/" directory.

Comment: I am not using GlassFishServer, i am running a standalone Appengine java application which is running locally on my system.

Answer (score -1):

Probably too late, but here is my answer: the root cause for NoSuchMethodError is that you have compiled your class with another version than the execution class. Please check the dependency tree of your main dependecies. My point is for com.google.api-client but I can´t assure that...

Bonus: difference between NoSuchMethodError and NoSuchMethodException in this [article](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com.es/2014/10/NoSuchMethodException-vs-NoSuchMethodError.html)